# How to parse a utf-8 encoded query parameter with Python 2.6

Tags: python, web.py, utf8-decode, urlparse

I have some lovely (Scandinavian?) user on my website complaining that [I cannot parse his username](http://councilroom.uservoice.com/forums/99487-general/suggestions/1570005-support-on-player-search?ref=title) in URLs, and hence I am showing him no results on his page on my website.

I am pretty sure that the browser encodes the requests as 
http://councilroom.com/player?player=G%C3%B6rling

I'd like to get the player string to become Görling rather than GÃ¶rling that is getting converted to.

I am using web.py with python 2.6 and attempting to parse the URL as follows

```
parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(web.ctx.fullpath)
query_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed_url.query))
target_player = query_dict['player']
```

Edit: With the help of unutbu, I fixed this by changing it to

```
query_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(web.ctx.env['QUERY_STRING']))
target_player = query_dict['player'].decode('utf-8')
```

I think webpy was mis-parsing the fullpath in web.ctx somehow, but the QUERY_STRING variable is unmolested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [4]: import urlparse

In [6]: parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse('http://councilroom.com/player?player=G%C3%B6rling')

In [7]: parsed_url
Out[7]: ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='councilroom.com', path='/player', params='', query='player=G%C3%B6rling', fragment='')

In [8]: query_dict = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(parsed_url.query))

In [9]: query_dict
Out[9]: {'player': 'G\xc3\xb6rling'}
```

Note the `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
In [10]: target_player = query_dict['player'].decode('utf-8')

In [11]: target_player
Out[11]: u'G\xf6rling'

In [12]: print(target_player)
Görling
```

---

PS. Somehow, the bytes in the `str` object `'G\xc3\xb6rling'` were being interpreted as a sequence of unicode code points, with the effect of turning `Görling` into `GÃ¶rling`:

```
In [3]: print(u'G\xc3\xb6rling')
GÃ¶rling
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem was that the web.ctx.fullpath variable was being filled incorrectly, and going back to the source data (as your example showed) in a more primitive data structure worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us unambiguously what you have got ... show us the value returned by `repr(target_player)`.

If the value is `'G\xc3\xb6rling'`, that is a UTF-8 encoded version of the player's correct name. To get unicode, you need to to decode it. Then you need to consider what encoding is being used to display it ... judging by the A-tilde and pilcrow characters that you showed, it's probably cp1252 (or latin1 aka iso-8859-1).